# Is there an exhaustive list of standard attributes?

Tags: rust

I'm looking for an exhaustive list of [attributes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/first-edition/attributes.html) that are available by default: without any external crates or experimental features enabled.

Does such a list exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the [Rust reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/attributes.html) contains a list of attributes (though it might not be up to date).

Quoting from the [Rust book section on attributes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/attributes.html) you linked:

> There is a full list of attributes [in the reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/attributes.html). Currently, you are 
>   not allowed to create your own attributes, the Rust compiler defines them.