# Is there a list of all cfg features?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Rust has the ability to [check configuration at build](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/conditional-compilation.html) time with, e.g., `#[cfg(target_os = "linux")]` or  `if cfg!(target_os = "linux") {...}`, where `target_os` is a *feature*.

Is there a list of all (or, at least, commonly used) features that can be checked in Rust?

---

See related question regarding *attributes* [Is there an exhaustive list of standard attributes anywhere?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37900513/is-there-an-exhaustive-list-of-standard-attributes-anywhere?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The ["Conditional compilation" section of the Reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/conditional-compilation.html) has a list of configurations that must be defined *(as of Rust 1.14)*:

- `target_arch` with values like:

  - `x86`
  - `x86_64`
  - `mips`
  - `powerpc`
  - `powerpc64`
  - `arm`
  - `aarch64`
- `target_os` with values like:

  - `windows`
  - `macos`
  - `ios`
  - `linux`
  - `android`
  - `freebsd`
  - `dragonfly`
  - `bitrig`
  - `openbsd`
  - `netbsd`
- `target_family` with values like:

  - `unix`
  - `windows`
- `unix` (shortcut for `target_family`)
- `windows` (shortcut for `target_family`)
- `target_env` with values like:

  - `gnu`
  - `msvc`
  - `musl`
  - `""` (empty string)
- `target_endian` with values:

  - `little`
  - `big`
- `target_pointer_width` with values like:

  - `32`
  - `64`
- `target_has_atomic` with values like:

  - `8`
  - `16`
  - `32`
  - `64`
  - `ptr`
- `target_vendor` with values like:

  - `apple`
  - `pc`
  - `unknown`
- `test`
- `debug_assertions`

Comment: thanks for list. Sadly it don't have any options to detect is it nightly or stable

Comment: @BogdanMart you might be interested in [this RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2523).

Comment: Is it also possible to specify Web Assembly this way?

Comment: Note that [Bitrig is no longer supported](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/60743)

Answer (score 9):

You can also use this command: `rustc --print target-list`.

Each triple are formatted as follows: **{arch}-{vendor}-{sys}-{abi}**.

For example, the triple '*arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf*' refers to:

1. architecture: arm
2. vendor: unknown. In this case, no vendor was specified.
3. system: linux
4. ABI: gnueabihf

Comment: This is helpful to know, but not useful in constructing `cfg` attributes, as system does not necessarily pertain to `target_os` (etc.; for example, system is `"darwin"` but `target_os` needs to be specified as `"macos"`).

Answer (score 3):

See also https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/all-the-rust-features/4322 for a comprehensive list of features.

Bear in mind that some / most of the features won't be stabilized so will only be available in nightly for some time and are subject to breaking improvements / upgrades until they are either stabilized or discontinued.

Features in rust nightly is survival of the fittest.