# Is it possible to write a test in Rust so it does not run on a specific operating system?

Tags: rust

I am writing a test:

```
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    #[test]
    fn test_something() {
        //content of test function
    }
}
```

Is it possible to make this test not run when using Windows and only run on Linux?

Answer (score 7):

You can choose to not compile the test at all

```
#[cfg(not(target_os = "windows"))]
#[test]
fn test_something() {
    //content of test function
}
```

Or you can choose to compile it but not run it:

```
#[test]
#[cfg_attr(target_os = "windows", ignore)]
fn test_something() {
    //content of test function
}
```

See also:

- [Is there a list of all cfg features?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41742046/155423)
- [Is it possible to conditionally derive with features?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42551113/155423)