# How to make a test for a function defined under some configuration?

Tags: unit-testing, rust, conditional-compilation

How to make a unit test for a function defined some configuration like what follows

```rust
struct I32Add;
impl I32Add{
    #[cfg(unstable)]
    fn add(x:i32, y:i32) -> i32{x+y}
}

#[test]
fn add_test(){
    assert_eq!(I32Add::add(1,2),3)
}
```

Of course, the test doesn't work. how to make it work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to write a test in Rust so it does not run on a specific operating system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49588087/is-it-possible-to-write-a-test-in-rust-so-it-does-not-run-on-a-specific-operatin)

Comment: @kmdreko this disables/enables the test on enabling/disabling the feature. My question is how to make a unit test i.e. in the same crate.

Comment: My proposal would be to add `#[cfg(unstable)]` to your test just as you've done for your function [as shown here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9dd4bdd0b186417e76c20e6706aa5d37). That way, if the function isn't there, the test isn't there so you don't get compilation issues. Is that not what the question is about?

Comment: *"My question is how to make a unit test i.e. in the same crate."* - I'm not sure I understand, `add_test` *is* a unit test and its in the same crate as `I32Add`...

Comment: @kmdreko the test doesn't work. 
```
running 0 tests

test result: ok. 0 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out; finished in 0.00s


running 0 tests

test result: ok. 0 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out; finished in 0.00s
```

Comment: So the question is how to check if the test passes or not in the same crate?

Comment: @kmdreko I think u should remove the closing suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `#[cfg(unstable)]` to your test just as you've done for your function. So the test is only compiled if that function is compiled:

```
#[cfg(unstable)]
#[test]
fn add_test() {
    assert_eq!(I32Add::add(1, 2), 3)
}
```

To get your function and the test to compile and run, you have to *enable* the `unstable` config option:

```
RUSTFLAGS="--cfg unstable" cargo test
```

---

However, I would recommended that you use a [cargo feature](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/features.html) instead of a config option for conditionally enabling portions of your code-base.

```
struct I32Add;
impl I32Add{
    #[cfg(feature = "unstable")]
    fn add(x:i32, y:i32) -> i32{x+y}
}

#[cfg(feature = "unstable")]
#[test]
fn add_test(){
    assert_eq!(I32Add::add(1,2),3)
}
```

with this in your `cargo.toml`:

```toml
[features]
unstable = []
```

And then run it like:

```
cargo test --features=unstable
```

See:

- [How to set cfg options to compile conditionally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57338478/how-to-set-cfg-options-to-compile-conditionally)
- [How do I use conditional compilation with `cfg` and Cargo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27632660/how-do-i-use-conditional-compilation-with-cfg-and-cargo)
- [Is it possible to write a test in Rust so it does not run on a specific operating system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49588087/is-it-possible-to-write-a-test-in-rust-so-it-does-not-run-on-a-specific-operatin)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding `#[cfg(unstable)]` to your *test*, you can always enable the *function* when testing (assuming the `cfg` doesn't protect from details such as operating system, rustc version, or any other detail that you cannot control):

```rust
impl I32Add{
    #[cfg(any(unstable, test))]
    fn add(x: i32, y: i32) -> i32 { x + y }
}
```