# How do I choose a module for serialization and deserialization based on platform?

Tags: rust, serde, conditional-compilation

Is there any way to add a platform based condition on `#[serde(with = "path_handling")]`?
So, basically I want to use this custome Serde method only in Inix and on Windows I want to use default way.

```
pub struct Res {
    pub last: bool,
    #[serde(with = "path_handling")] // ignore this line on windows as path_handling module contains unix specific logic
    pub path: PathBuf,
}
```

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42551113/is-it-possible-to-conditionally-enable-an-attribute-like-derive https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41742046/is-there-a-list-of-all-cfg-features

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`cfg_attr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/conditional-compilation.html#the-cfg_attr-attribute) and [`target_family`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/conditional-compilation.html#target_family).

```rust
pub struct Res {
    pub last: bool,
    #[cfg_attr(target_family = "unix", serde(with = "path_handling"))]
    pub path: PathBuf,
}
```