# Rust: Is there a list of what target is a member of what "target-family"?

Tags: rust, compilation, rust-cargo, conditional-compilation

When trying to write or interpret `cfg` statements like e.g.

```rust
#[cfg(all(unix, not(target_arch = "wasm32")))]
```

from the `atty` crate,
I am sometimes unsure what exactly `unix` means here.  (Apparently it includes `wasm`?)

---

**Is there a full list of what rust compiler targets are in what target-family?**

[The cfg doc in the rust reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/conditional-compilation.html) does not seem to have one.

Comment: Related: [Is there a list of all cfg features?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41742046/is-there-a-list-of-all-cfg-features) I'm not aware of any better resource than the link you found yourself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rust nightly now has `--print all-target-specs-json`,
which has this information.
On `rustc 1.72.0-nightly (8c74a5d27 2023-06-14)`,
I was able to gather the following output using

```bash
rustc +nightly -Z unstable-options --print all-target-specs-json | jq '[ to_entries[] | { "target": .key, "arch": .value.arch, "os": .value.os, "target-family": .value."target-family" } ]'
```

---

```json
[
    {
        "target": "aarch64-apple-darwin", 
        "arch": "aarch64", 
        "os": "macos", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "aarch64-apple-ios", 
        "arch": "aarch64", 
        "os": "ios", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "aarch64-apple-ios-macabi", 
        "arch": "aarch64", 
        "os": "ios", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "aarch64-apple-ios-sim", 
        "arch": "aarch64", 
        "os": "ios", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "aarch64-apple-tvos", 
        "arch": "aarch64", 
        "os": "tvos", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "aarch64-apple-watchos-sim", 
        "arch": "aarch64", 
        "os": "watchos", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "aarch64-fuchsia", 
        "arch": "aarch64", 
        "os": "fuchsia", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "aarch64-kmc-solid_asp3", 
        "arch": "aarch64", 
        "os": "solid_asp3", 
        "target-family": null
    }, 
    {
        "target": "aarch64-linux-android", 
        "arch": "aarch64", 
        "os": "android", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "aarch64-nintendo-switch-freestanding", 
        "arch": "aarch64", 
        "os": "horizon", 
        "target-family": null
    }, 
    {
        "target": "aarch64-pc-windows-gnullvm", 
        "arch": "aarch64", 
        "os": "windows", 
        "target-family": ["windows"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "aarch64-pc-windows-msvc", 
        "arch": "aarch64", 
        "os": "windows", 
        "target-family": ["windows"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "aarch64-unknown-freebsd", 
        "arch": "aarch64", 
        "os": "freebsd", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "aarch64-unknown-fuchsia", 
        "arch": "aarch64", 
        "os": "fuchsia", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "aarch64-unknown-hermit", 
        "arch": "aarch64", 
        "os": "hermit", 
        "target-family": null
    }, 
    {
        "target": "aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu", 
        "arch": "aarch64", 
        "os": "linux", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu_ilp32", 
        "arch": "aarch64", 
        "os": "linux", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "aarch64-unknown-linux-musl", 
        "arch": "aarch64", 
        "os": "linux", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "aarch64-unknown-linux-ohos", 
        "arch": "aarch64", 
        "os": "linux", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "aarch64-unknown-netbsd", 
        "arch": "aarch64", 
        "os": "netbsd", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "aarch64-unknown-none", 
        "arch": "aarch64", 
        "os": null, 
        "target-family": null
    }, 
    {
        "target": "aarch64-unknown-none-softfloat", 
        "arch": "aarch64", 
        "os": null, 
        "target-family": null
    }, 
    {
        "target": "aarch64-unknown-nto-qnx710", 
        "arch": "aarch64", 
        "os": "nto", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "aarch64-unknown-openbsd", 
        "arch": "aarch64", 
        "os": "openbsd", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "aarch64-unknown-redox", 
        "arch": "aarch64", 
        "os": "redox", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "aarch64-unknown-uefi", 
        "arch": "aarch64", 
        "os": "uefi", 
        "target-family": null
    }, 
    {
        "target": "aarch64-uwp-windows-msvc", 
        "arch": "aarch64", 
        "os": "windows", 
        "target-family": ["windows"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "aarch64-wrs-vxworks", 
        "arch": "aarch64", 
        "os": "vxworks", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "aarch64_be-unknown-linux-gnu", 
        "arch": "aarch64", 
        "os": "linux", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "aarch64_be-unknown-linux-gnu_ilp32", 
        "arch": "aarch64", 
        "os": "linux", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "arm-linux-androideabi", 
        "arch": "arm", 
        "os": "android", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi", 
        "arch": "arm", 
        "os": "linux", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf", 
        "arch": "arm", 
        "os": "linux", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "arm-unknown-linux-musleabi", 
        "arch": "arm", 
        "os": "linux", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "arm-unknown-linux-musleabihf", 
        "arch": "arm", 
        "os": "linux", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "arm64_32-apple-watchos", 
        "arch": "aarch64", 
        "os": "watchos", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "armeb-unknown-linux-gnueabi", 
        "arch": "arm", 
        "os": "linux", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "armebv7r-none-eabi", 
        "arch": "arm", 
        "os": null, 
        "target-family": null
    }, 
    {
        "target": "armebv7r-none-eabihf", 
        "arch": "arm", 
        "os": null, 
        "target-family": null
    }, 
    {
        "target": "armv4t-none-eabi", 
        "arch": "arm", 
        "os": null, 
        "target-family": null
    }, 
    {
        "target": "armv4t-unknown-linux-gnueabi", 
        "arch": "arm", 
        "os": "linux", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "armv5te-none-eabi", 
        "arch": "arm", 
        "os": null, 
        "target-family": null
    }, 
    {
        "target": "armv5te-unknown-linux-gnueabi", 
        "arch": "arm", 
        "os": "linux", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "armv5te-unknown-linux-musleabi", 
        "arch": "arm", 
        "os": "linux", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "armv5te-unknown-linux-uclibceabi", 
        "arch": "arm", 
        "os": "linux", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "armv6-unknown-freebsd", 
        "arch": "arm", 
        "os": "freebsd", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "armv6-unknown-netbsd-eabihf", 
        "arch": "arm", 
        "os": "netbsd", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "armv6k-nintendo-3ds", 
        "arch": "arm", 
        "os": "horizon", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "armv7-apple-ios", 
        "arch": "arm", 
        "os": "ios", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "armv7-linux-androideabi", 
        "arch": "arm", 
        "os": "android", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "armv7-sony-vita-newlibeabihf", 
        "arch": "arm", 
        "os": "vita", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "armv7-unknown-freebsd", 
        "arch": "arm", 
        "os": "freebsd", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabi", 
        "arch": "arm", 
        "os": "linux", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf", 
        "arch": "arm", 
        "os": "linux", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "armv7-unknown-linux-musleabi", 
        "arch": "arm", 
        "os": "linux", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "armv7-unknown-linux-musleabihf", 
        "arch": "arm", 
        "os": "linux", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "armv7-unknown-linux-ohos", 
        "arch": "arm", 
        "os": "linux", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "armv7-unknown-linux-uclibceabi", 
        "arch": "arm", 
        "os": "linux", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "armv7-unknown-linux-uclibceabihf", 
        "arch": "arm", 
        "os": "linux", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "armv7-unknown-netbsd-eabihf", 
        "arch": "arm", 
        "os": "netbsd", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "armv7-wrs-vxworks-eabihf", 
        "arch": "arm", 
        "os": "vxworks", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "armv7a-kmc-solid_asp3-eabi", 
        "arch": "arm", 
        "os": "solid_asp3", 
        "target-family": null
    }, 
    {
        "target": "armv7a-kmc-solid_asp3-eabihf", 
        "arch": "arm", 
        "os": "solid_asp3", 
        "target-family": null
    }, 
    {
        "target": "armv7a-none-eabi", 
        "arch": "arm", 
        "os": null, 
        "target-family": null
    }, 
    {
        "target": "armv7a-none-eabihf", 
        "arch": "arm", 
        "os": null, 
        "target-family": null
    }, 
    {
        "target": "armv7k-apple-watchos", 
        "arch": "arm", 
        "os": "watchos", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "armv7r-none-eabi", 
        "arch": "arm", 
        "os": null, 
        "target-family": null
    }, 
    {
        "target": "armv7r-none-eabihf", 
        "arch": "arm", 
        "os": null, 
        "target-family": null
    }, 
    {
        "target": "armv7s-apple-ios", 
        "arch": "arm", 
        "os": "ios", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "asmjs-unknown-emscripten", 
        "arch": "wasm32", 
        "os": "emscripten", 
        "target-family": ["unix", "wasm"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "avr-unknown-gnu-atmega328", 
        "arch": "avr", 
        "os": null, 
        "target-family": null
    }, 
    {
        "target": "bpfeb-unknown-none", 
        "arch": "bpf", 
        "os": null, 
        "target-family": null
    }, 
    {
        "target": "bpfel-unknown-none", 
        "arch": "bpf", 
        "os": null, 
        "target-family": null
    }, 
    {
        "target": "hexagon-unknown-linux-musl", 
        "arch": "hexagon", 
        "os": "linux", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "i386-apple-ios", 
        "arch": "x86", 
        "os": "ios", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "i586-pc-nto-qnx700", 
        "arch": "x86", 
        "os": "nto", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "i586-pc-windows-msvc", 
        "arch": "x86", 
        "os": "windows", 
        "target-family": ["windows"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "i586-unknown-linux-gnu", 
        "arch": "x86", 
        "os": "linux", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "i586-unknown-linux-musl", 
        "arch": "x86", 
        "os": "linux", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "i686-apple-darwin", 
        "arch": "x86", 
        "os": "macos", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "i686-linux-android", 
        "arch": "x86", 
        "os": "android", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "i686-pc-windows-gnu", 
        "arch": "x86", 
        "os": "windows", 
        "target-family": ["windows"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "i686-pc-windows-msvc", 
        "arch": "x86", 
        "os": "windows", 
        "target-family": ["windows"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "i686-unknown-freebsd", 
        "arch": "x86", 
        "os": "freebsd", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "i686-unknown-haiku", 
        "arch": "x86", 
        "os": "haiku", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "i686-unknown-linux-gnu", 
        "arch": "x86", 
        "os": "linux", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "i686-unknown-linux-musl", 
        "arch": "x86", 
        "os": "linux", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "i686-unknown-netbsd", 
        "arch": "x86", 
        "os": "netbsd", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "i686-unknown-openbsd", 
        "arch": "x86", 
        "os": "openbsd", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "i686-unknown-uefi", 
        "arch": "x86", 
        "os": "uefi", 
        "target-family": null
    }, 
    {
        "target": "i686-uwp-windows-gnu", 
        "arch": "x86", 
        "os": "windows", 
        "target-family": ["windows"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "i686-uwp-windows-msvc", 
        "arch": "x86", 
        "os": "windows", 
        "target-family": ["windows"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "i686-wrs-vxworks", 
        "arch": "x86", 
        "os": "vxworks", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "loongarch64-unknown-linux-gnu", 
        "arch": "loongarch64", 
        "os": "linux", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "loongarch64-unknown-none", 
        "arch": "loongarch64", 
        "os": null, 
        "target-family": null
    }, 
    {
        "target": "loongarch64-unknown-none-softfloat", 
        "arch": "loongarch64", 
        "os": null, 
        "target-family": null
    }, 
    {
        "target": "m68k-unknown-linux-gnu", 
        "arch": "m68k", 
        "os": "linux", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "mips-unknown-linux-gnu", 
        "arch": "mips", 
        "os": "linux", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "mips-unknown-linux-musl", 
        "arch": "mips", 
        "os": "linux", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "mips-unknown-linux-uclibc", 
        "arch": "mips", 
        "os": "linux", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "mips64-openwrt-linux-musl", 
        "arch": "mips64", 
        "os": "linux", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "mips64-unknown-linux-gnuabi64", 
        "arch": "mips64", 
        "os": "linux", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "mips64-unknown-linux-muslabi64", 
        "arch": "mips64", 
        "os": "linux", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "mips64el-unknown-linux-gnuabi64", 
        "arch": "mips64", 
        "os": "linux", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "mips64el-unknown-linux-muslabi64", 
        "arch": "mips64", 
        "os": "linux", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "mipsel-sony-psp", 
        "arch": "mips", 
        "os": "psp", 
        "target-family": null
    }, 
    {
        "target": "mipsel-sony-psx", 
        "arch": "mips", 
        "os": null, 
        "target-family": null
    }, 
    {
        "target": "mipsel-unknown-linux-gnu", 
        "arch": "mips", 
        "os": "linux", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "mipsel-unknown-linux-musl", 
        "arch": "mips", 
        "os": "linux", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "mipsel-unknown-linux-uclibc", 
        "arch": "mips", 
        "os": "linux", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "mipsel-unknown-none", 
        "arch": "mips", 
        "os": null, 
        "target-family": null
    }, 
    {
        "target": "mipsisa32r6-unknown-linux-gnu", 
        "arch": "mips", 
        "os": "linux", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "mipsisa32r6el-unknown-linux-gnu", 
        "arch": "mips", 
        "os": "linux", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "mipsisa64r6-unknown-linux-gnuabi64", 
        "arch": "mips64", 
        "os": "linux", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "mipsisa64r6el-unknown-linux-gnuabi64", 
        "arch": "mips64", 
        "os": "linux", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "msp430-none-elf", 
        "arch": "msp430", 
        "os": null, 
        "target-family": null
    }, 
    {
        "target": "nvptx64-nvidia-cuda", 
        "arch": "nvptx64", 
        "os": "cuda", 
        "target-family": null
    }, 
    {
        "target": "powerpc-unknown-freebsd", 
        "arch": "powerpc", 
        "os": "freebsd", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "powerpc-unknown-linux-gnu", 
        "arch": "powerpc", 
        "os": "linux", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "powerpc-unknown-linux-gnuspe", 
        "arch": "powerpc", 
        "os": "linux", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "powerpc-unknown-linux-musl", 
        "arch": "powerpc", 
        "os": "linux", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "powerpc-unknown-netbsd", 
        "arch": "powerpc", 
        "os": "netbsd", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "powerpc-unknown-openbsd", 
        "arch": "powerpc", 
        "os": "openbsd", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "powerpc-wrs-vxworks", 
        "arch": "powerpc", 
        "os": "vxworks", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "powerpc-wrs-vxworks-spe", 
        "arch": "powerpc", 
        "os": "vxworks", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "powerpc64-ibm-aix", 
        "arch": "powerpc64", 
        "os": "aix", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "powerpc64-unknown-freebsd", 
        "arch": "powerpc64", 
        "os": "freebsd", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "powerpc64-unknown-linux-gnu", 
        "arch": "powerpc64", 
        "os": "linux", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "powerpc64-unknown-linux-musl", 
        "arch": "powerpc64", 
        "os": "linux", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "powerpc64-unknown-openbsd", 
        "arch": "powerpc64", 
        "os": "openbsd", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "powerpc64-wrs-vxworks", 
        "arch": "powerpc64", 
        "os": "vxworks", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "powerpc64le-unknown-freebsd", 
        "arch": "powerpc64", 
        "os": "freebsd", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "powerpc64le-unknown-linux-gnu", 
        "arch": "powerpc64", 
        "os": "linux", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "powerpc64le-unknown-linux-musl", 
        "arch": "powerpc64", 
        "os": "linux", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "riscv32gc-unknown-linux-gnu", 
        "arch": "riscv32", 
        "os": "linux", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "riscv32gc-unknown-linux-musl", 
        "arch": "riscv32", 
        "os": "linux", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "riscv32i-unknown-none-elf", 
        "arch": "riscv32", 
        "os": null, 
        "target-family": null
    }, 
    {
        "target": "riscv32im-unknown-none-elf", 
        "arch": "riscv32", 
        "os": null, 
        "target-family": null
    }, 
    {
        "target": "riscv32imac-esp-espidf", 
        "arch": "riscv32", 
        "os": "espidf", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "riscv32imac-unknown-none-elf", 
        "arch": "riscv32", 
        "os": null, 
        "target-family": null
    }, 
    {
        "target": "riscv32imac-unknown-xous-elf", 
        "arch": "riscv32", 
        "os": "xous", 
        "target-family": null
    }, 
    {
        "target": "riscv32imc-esp-espidf", 
        "arch": "riscv32", 
        "os": "espidf", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "riscv32imc-unknown-none-elf", 
        "arch": "riscv32", 
        "os": null, 
        "target-family": null
    }, 
    {
        "target": "riscv64gc-unknown-freebsd", 
        "arch": "riscv64", 
        "os": "freebsd", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "riscv64gc-unknown-fuchsia", 
        "arch": "riscv64", 
        "os": "fuchsia", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "riscv64gc-unknown-linux-gnu", 
        "arch": "riscv64", 
        "os": "linux", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "riscv64gc-unknown-linux-musl", 
        "arch": "riscv64", 
        "os": "linux", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "riscv64gc-unknown-none-elf", 
        "arch": "riscv64", 
        "os": null, 
        "target-family": null
    }, 
    {
        "target": "riscv64gc-unknown-openbsd", 
        "arch": "riscv64", 
        "os": "openbsd", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "riscv64imac-unknown-none-elf", 
        "arch": "riscv64", 
        "os": null, 
        "target-family": null
    }, 
    {
        "target": "s390x-unknown-linux-gnu", 
        "arch": "s390x", 
        "os": "linux", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "s390x-unknown-linux-musl", 
        "arch": "s390x", 
        "os": "linux", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "sparc-unknown-linux-gnu", 
        "arch": "sparc", 
        "os": "linux", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "sparc64-unknown-linux-gnu", 
        "arch": "sparc64", 
        "os": "linux", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "sparc64-unknown-netbsd", 
        "arch": "sparc64", 
        "os": "netbsd", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "sparc64-unknown-openbsd", 
        "arch": "sparc64", 
        "os": "openbsd", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "sparcv9-sun-solaris", 
        "arch": "sparc64", 
        "os": "solaris", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "thumbv4t-none-eabi", 
        "arch": "arm", 
        "os": null, 
        "target-family": null
    }, 
    {
        "target": "thumbv5te-none-eabi", 
        "arch": "arm", 
        "os": null, 
        "target-family": null
    }, 
    {
        "target": "thumbv6m-none-eabi", 
        "arch": "arm", 
        "os": null, 
        "target-family": null
    }, 
    {
        "target": "thumbv7a-pc-windows-msvc", 
        "arch": "arm", 
        "os": "windows", 
        "target-family": ["windows"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "thumbv7a-uwp-windows-msvc", 
        "arch": "arm", 
        "os": "windows", 
        "target-family": ["windows"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "thumbv7em-none-eabi", 
        "arch": "arm", 
        "os": null, 
        "target-family": null
    }, 
    {
        "target": "thumbv7em-none-eabihf", 
        "arch": "arm", 
        "os": null, 
        "target-family": null
    }, 
    {
        "target": "thumbv7m-none-eabi", 
        "arch": "arm", 
        "os": null, 
        "target-family": null
    }, 
    {
        "target": "thumbv7neon-linux-androideabi", 
        "arch": "arm", 
        "os": "android", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "thumbv7neon-unknown-linux-gnueabihf", 
        "arch": "arm", 
        "os": "linux", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "thumbv7neon-unknown-linux-musleabihf", 
        "arch": "arm", 
        "os": "linux", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "thumbv8m.base-none-eabi", 
        "arch": "arm", 
        "os": null, 
        "target-family": null
    }, 
    {
        "target": "thumbv8m.main-none-eabi", 
        "arch": "arm", 
        "os": null, 
        "target-family": null
    }, 
    {
        "target": "thumbv8m.main-none-eabihf", 
        "arch": "arm", 
        "os": null, 
        "target-family": null
    }, 
    {
        "target": "wasm32-unknown-emscripten", 
        "arch": "wasm32", 
        "os": "emscripten", 
        "target-family": ["unix", "wasm"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "wasm32-unknown-unknown", 
        "arch": "wasm32", 
        "os": "unknown", 
        "target-family": ["wasm"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "wasm32-wasi", 
        "arch": "wasm32", 
        "os": "wasi", 
        "target-family": ["wasm"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "wasm64-unknown-unknown", 
        "arch": "wasm64", 
        "os": "unknown", 
        "target-family": ["wasm"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "x86_64-apple-darwin", 
        "arch": "x86_64", 
        "os": "macos", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "x86_64-apple-ios", 
        "arch": "x86_64", 
        "os": "ios", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "x86_64-apple-ios-macabi", 
        "arch": "x86_64", 
        "os": "ios", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "x86_64-apple-tvos", 
        "arch": "x86_64", 
        "os": "tvos", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "x86_64-apple-watchos-sim", 
        "arch": "x86_64", 
        "os": "watchos", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "x86_64-fortanix-unknown-sgx", 
        "arch": "x86_64", 
        "os": "unknown", 
        "target-family": null
    }, 
    {
        "target": "x86_64-fuchsia", 
        "arch": "x86_64", 
        "os": "fuchsia", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "x86_64-linux-android", 
        "arch": "x86_64", 
        "os": "android", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "x86_64-pc-nto-qnx710", 
        "arch": "x86_64", 
        "os": "nto", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "x86_64-pc-solaris", 
        "arch": "x86_64", 
        "os": "solaris", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "x86_64-pc-windows-gnu", 
        "arch": "x86_64", 
        "os": "windows", 
        "target-family": ["windows"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "x86_64-pc-windows-gnullvm", 
        "arch": "x86_64", 
        "os": "windows", 
        "target-family": ["windows"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "x86_64-pc-windows-msvc", 
        "arch": "x86_64", 
        "os": "windows", 
        "target-family": ["windows"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "x86_64-sun-solaris", 
        "arch": "x86_64", 
        "os": "solaris", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "x86_64-unknown-dragonfly", 
        "arch": "x86_64", 
        "os": "dragonfly", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "x86_64-unknown-freebsd", 
        "arch": "x86_64", 
        "os": "freebsd", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "x86_64-unknown-fuchsia", 
        "arch": "x86_64", 
        "os": "fuchsia", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "x86_64-unknown-haiku", 
        "arch": "x86_64", 
        "os": "haiku", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "x86_64-unknown-hermit", 
        "arch": "x86_64", 
        "os": "hermit", 
        "target-family": null
    }, 
    {
        "target": "x86_64-unknown-illumos", 
        "arch": "x86_64", 
        "os": "illumos", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "x86_64-unknown-l4re-uclibc", 
        "arch": "x86_64", 
        "os": "l4re", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu", 
        "arch": "x86_64", 
        "os": "linux", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "x86_64-unknown-linux-gnux32", 
        "arch": "x86_64", 
        "os": "linux", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "x86_64-unknown-linux-musl", 
        "arch": "x86_64", 
        "os": "linux", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "x86_64-unknown-netbsd", 
        "arch": "x86_64", 
        "os": "netbsd", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "x86_64-unknown-none", 
        "arch": "x86_64", 
        "os": null, 
        "target-family": null
    }, 
    {
        "target": "x86_64-unknown-openbsd", 
        "arch": "x86_64", 
        "os": "openbsd", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "x86_64-unknown-redox", 
        "arch": "x86_64", 
        "os": "redox", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "x86_64-unknown-uefi", 
        "arch": "x86_64", 
        "os": "uefi", 
        "target-family": null
    }, 
    {
        "target": "x86_64-uwp-windows-gnu", 
        "arch": "x86_64", 
        "os": "windows", 
        "target-family": ["windows"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "x86_64-uwp-windows-msvc", 
        "arch": "x86_64", 
        "os": "windows", 
        "target-family": ["windows"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "x86_64-wrs-vxworks", 
        "arch": "x86_64", 
        "os": "vxworks", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }, 
    {
        "target": "x86_64h-apple-darwin", 
        "arch": "x86_64", 
        "os": "macos", 
        "target-family": ["unix"]
    }
]
```

Comment: If anybody has an online reference instead of this one time dump I would still accept their answer over this, but for now this is good enough for me :).